# delta packages installation on local with pyspark: ivy-cache file not found

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

I am triying to use delta format so trying this from this site [delta lake](https://docs.delta.io/0.8.0/quick-start.html). On cmd `pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"` but giving
error like.

[image: this is the error]

I tried manually put jar file but not working.

Comment: What is the Spark version? But most probably you have problem with the ivy cache, I typically just remove that folder and allow Spark to redownload jars

Comment: I am using spark 3.0.1

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).